# Can we create both parent and child in a row in OneToMany unidirectionnal relationship using Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, persistence, hibernate-onetomany

I'm trying to understand how Spring JPA works in creating (POST http action) resources under relationships (@OneToMany).
I have 2 simples classes, `Product` and `Comment`. One `product`is related to many `comments`.

Product class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private List<Comment> comments;

... getters and setters are also implemented

}
```

Comment class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    private int commentId;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int productId;

... getters and setters

}
```

I implemented this *@OneToMany relationship* as unidirectional, on purpose, just to understand how it works.
I also made basic controller and repository classes for both resources.
What I am trying to understand is, when I send a Post request (using postman) to `"/products"` with a new product and its new comments at the same time as below :

[image]

I dont understand why I'm getting an error 500 from hibernate that successfully created the new product but did not for the comment because the comment `is missing the foreign key.` Of course I the get issue here. But since my relationship is unidirectional from the product, it should mean the product is leading the relation. So spring should synchronize the *persisting* operation (I added `CascadeType.PERSIST`), based on the product. In my request body, the product's `comments list` is filled with two new comments. This is supposed to set the `comments list` of the product and tell to hibernate that this product has two new `comments`.
So my question is, why doesnt hibernate create the product then get the new id of this product and then create the two new comments with a foreign key set to this new product id ?
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: can you share how are you saving the entities?

Comment: Hi, thank you for giving me a hand.  I’m just using the saving method of the repository : ‘’productRepository.save(product);’’ where I get the product from the @RequestBody as a method argument in my rest controller

Answer (score 0):

so basically i am assuming you want on call of `productRepository.save(product)` it automatically saves comments with it, if so you need to change cascade to `@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})` otherwise you need manually to call both repositories to save entities, i tested your code, and only thing that is missing is to change cascade type

Comment: Hi, thank you again for your help. Yes exactly, I want also the comments to be saved automatically. I dont understand why I have to put « CascadeType.ALL ». Isnt « CascadeType.PERSIST » supposed to be enough to tell hibernate that « when I create a product, if that product contains new comments, create them too » especially when it is a @OneToMany unidirectional relationship ?

Comment: depends, both are valid if you want to let hibernate to only save child entity when calling parent `.save()` then `CascadeType.PERSIST` is enough but if you want an update, remove, or merge together then I suggest using `CascadeType.ALL` because in your case it is unidirectional meaning parent is the most important, check example 158 in [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one) for more information about cascading in unidirectional

Comment: Like you said, I just want to save child entity, thats why I really focused on CascadeType.PERSIST, so my question is why isnt it working with CascadeType.PERSIST to save child from parent (since parent is leading the relationship...) ?

Comment: it works fine for me both with `CascadeType.PERSIST` and `CascadeType.ALL`

Comment: did you use something else like transactions or anything else ? Also can you add "spring.jpa.show-sql = true" on your file applications.properties and please share with me what console prints about hibernate database operations

Comment: sure, `Hibernate: insert into product (description, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into comment (content, product_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update comment set product_id=? where comment_id=?` this is the log, full code is here (https://github.com/hammafataka/st_ov_answer)

Comment: thank you a lot for taking some time. I have another question though, how come in your logs, in the comment insert request, hibernate knows the value of "produit_id", because on my side, I get the error from here, throwing foreign key error and saying the produit_id is not valid

Comment: maybe your db is wrongly created, i suggest to delete the table and let hibernate create it automatically as i have defined in `application.yaml` in github